# sql server 2008 return value getting shortened when using ISNULL and NULLIF

Tags: sql-server-2008, isnull

I have this select statement where I check whether phone number in null or empty and if they are then I would return 'No Phone Number is available'. Like this

```
SELECT 
      Name, 
      ISNULL(NULLIF(Phone, ''), 'No Phone Number is available') AS Phone
FROM Person
```

But when the phone number is null or empty I am not getting the full text 'No phone number is available'. Only the first 20 characters is getting returned. The length of Phone field is also 20. So I think this is returning text depending on the length of the phone field.

Is there a way to correct this without changing the field length?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are correct.

ISNULL uses the datatype and length of the first parameter. COALESCE takes the "highest precedence" one. So:

```
COALESCE(NULLIF(Phone, ''), 'No Phone Number is available') AS Phone
```

Or

```
ISNULL(NULLIF(CAST(Phone as varchar(30)), ''), 'No Phone Number is available') AS Phone
```